# Android: ksoap, "UnknownHostException:host is unresolved" depending on API

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-ksoap2

thanks for your attention.

I have a problem on using ksoap2 to call a webservice via android.

I have some function to call a webservice.

```
public String CallWebServiceFunction()
{
        String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://MyWeb.com/";
        String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://MyWeb.com/pvws.asmx";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://MyWeb.com/SoapAction";
        String OPERATION_NAME = "SoapAction";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

        PropertyInfo prop1 = new PropertyInfo();
        prop1.setName("prop1");
        prop1.setValue("1");

        request.addProperty(prop1);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response=null;
        try
        {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            response=exception.toString();
        }

        return response.toString();

}
```

When I use emulator (or real device), which using ***API 16 or above (Android 4.x) - everything is OK***, function gets correct response from webservice. But when I use emulator (or real device) with ***API 7 (Android 2.x) - then I get an exception***

**"java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: MyWeb.com:80"**

I use the same code in both cases, trying one after another - and I get different results

Did anybody has any ideas?

**UPD1**: Permission section from my manifest is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**UPD2**: **Hypothesis**.
Initially I created my app for targetSdkVersion=16. Therefore I use multi-threaded code, when I call webservice via Internet. Maybe, when it works with API7, source code shouldn't be multi-threaded?

**UPD3**:  Hypothesis was wrong. Calling webservice from main thread causes the same exception.

But I noticed, that when I run my project on another computer - it works correctly. Despite I use the same code.

Comment: please post permission section from Manifest XML

Comment: I added my permission section above

Answer (score 1):

```
UnknownHostException:host is unresolved
```

*Make sure you have added permission* in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and *also Make sure its added inside* `<manifest>` tag  not inside any other tags like  `<application>` etc

***PS.***

*Also Make sure for following permissions*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I added my permission section above.
And I have to stress - when I use API16-emulator - everything is all right. Therefore, everything is OK both with internet connection and with "MyWeb.com"

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission. But adding of this permission didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think for Android 2.x absent `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Try it,

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but unfortunately exception still appears

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data connection or wifi is ON

then go to manifest and check  for internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```